# System.getenv("TEST_HOME") is returning null

Tags: java, environment-variables, system-variable

I am working on a ubuntu 14.0.4 machine.

I exported a variable TEST_HOME in my `.bashrc` file using

```
export TEST_HOME=/home/dev/code/test
```

When I tried `echo $TEST_HOME` from terminal, it returned `/home/dev/code/test`

So far, so good.

> **When I try from Java code :**
>
> `String value = System.getenv("TEST_HOME");`
>
> `value` is null.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: For that variable to be in Java's environment, you will have to start the Java process from a shell where you have that variable set. Did you?

Comment: @folkol I did not export this variable in a particular shell/terminal. I added it's entry in `.bashrc`

Comment: close and reopen your terminal to refresh .bashrc defined changes

Comment: This [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) might help you.

Comment: @vikingsteve I am not able to get this value from Java code. I am able to get it's value  from terminal.

Comment: 1) Kill java process 2) Restart session 3) Try it again

Comment: @bigdestroyer I am writing java code in Eclipse IDE. I killed eclispe instance, restarted it again it's null.

Comment: Try killing java from process manager

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mentioning the variable in `.bashrc` will work only for programs started from shell. For system wide environment variables mention it in `/etc/environment`.

Refer [Ubuntu Environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: currently only path variable is there in my `/etc/environment`. Do I need to `export TEST_HOME=/home/dev/code/test` in `/etc/environment`?

Comment: I added `export TEST_HOME=/home/dev/code/test` in `/etc/environment`. Now `echo $TEST_HOME` is returning nothing (I restarted terminal), same null from Java code (I restarted eclipse) Do I need to restart machine for this?

Comment: This [Reload env](http://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting) will help, to avoid restarting machine.

Answer (score 1):

`.bashrc` would set environment variable only for bash shell. To set it system wide set it in `/etc/environment` file.

Since you are using eclipse, and it does not run within bash shell, it is not getting the variable you are setting. If you run your programme using java command line in your terminal then it should get it.

Setting variable in `/etc/environment` would make it available to eclipse. You will need to restart your machine once you update `/etc/environment`.